# Accessing #defined variables from static methods in C++

Tags: c++, methods, static, header, c-preprocessor

I have header file A with code,

```
#define varA 1
```

And a header file B in which I have included the header file. I have the following static method in header file B,

```
static void MakeBFromA(){ 
int varB = varA;
}
```

I get an error that `varA` is undefined. But if I move `#define varA 1` to header file B it works fine. Why can't I use a `#define` variable from another file in my static method?

Comment: you can declare #define in other files, actually it's a best practice to have one header file concentrating all your general use defines. do you have varA defined else where? BTW: a coding standard is to have all letters of a define capitals like so: VAR_A

Answer (score 1):

`#define` is a **preprocessor** construct.
It only applies to the current file.

Instead, you can make a C++ `const`.

Comment: okay that solved it. But I'm confused, I can use my #define variable in any other file as long as I include the header. its only in static functions where it becomes unavailable.